# How to add rules to allow traffic on some port range for nodePort on aws EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-security-group

My exposed service on `nodePort` seems to not allow traffic through it.

So how to add rules to allow traffic for that port range on `CLI` not on the console?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `EC2` Security groups

There is a [security group](https://us-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-west-1#SecurityGroups:) on your screen.

See more about security groups:

- [EC2 Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#security-group-rules)
- [Creating a Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html#creating-security-group)

### `CLI` for `AWS Security groups`

As for `CLI` for working with `AWS Security groups`, see this article: [Creating, Configuring, and Deleting Security Groups for Amazon EC2 - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-sg.html)

```
$ aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name my-sg --description "My security group" --vpc-id vpc-1a2b3c4d
{
    "GroupId": "sg-903004f8"
}

$ aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-903004f8 --protocol tcp --port 3389 --cidr 203.0.113.0/24
```

> The following command adds another rule to enable SSH to instances in the same security group.

```
$ aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-903004f8 --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr 203.0.113.0/24
```

> To view the changes to the security group, run the [describe-security-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html) command.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids `sg-903004f8`
```

O/P is:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "Description": "My security group"
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "203.0.113.0/24"
                        }
                    ]
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "FromPort": 22
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "my-sg",
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "GroupId": "sg-903004f8"
        }
    ]
}
```

### P.S. `awless.io` - A Mighty CLI for AWS

There is also a bit outdated but still convenient `CLI` tool: 
[wallix/awless: A Mighty CLI for AWS](https://github.com/wallix/awless)

> A Mighty CLI for AWS http://awless.io/

Here the [Medium post about it](https://medium.com/@hbbio/awless-io-a-mighty-cli-for-aws-a0d48bdb59a4)